# How do I invoke the nothrow version of delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have the following code, which doesn't compile:

```
int *p = new(nothrow) int;
delete (nothrow) p; //Error
```

The error I get is:

> error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'const std::nothrow_t' to 'void*'

Does a `nothrow` version of `delete` exist? If so, how can I invoke it?

---

In C++: The Complete Reference, it's given that it exists but I saw different opinions online, hence the confusion.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30hb2y79(v=VS.90).aspx) also talks about its existence, but I couldn't find how it can be used in code.

[Here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t457132-delete-nothrow.html), some people are saying that there is no such thing.

Comment: Your MSDN link talks about the existence of `nothrow`, but *that* was never in any doubt. It's *`delete`* that everyone's telling you has no `nothrow` version, and they're right.

Comment: If that book is the Schildt one, you should (unfortunetly) throw it away. That guy is terrible, and has no idea what he's talking about when it comes to the language.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A `std::nothrow_t` deallocation function exists, but you cannot call it with a `delete` expression.

The deallocation function is there for completeness. If a `new` expression fails because of an exception, the compiler needs to free the memory it allocated via `operator new` with a **matching** call to `operator delete`. So there needs to be an `operator delete` that accepts a `std::nothrow_t`, to allow this.

(That is, in general, a `new` expression with the form `new (args...) T` will allocate memory with a call to `operator new(sizeof(T), args...)`. To "match" means to call `operator delete` with the same arguments, except the first.)

Note you can call the operator directly: `operator delete(memory, std::nothrow);`. However, a `delete` expression never calls a global deallocation function with additional parameters.

---

So you can "call" it with:

```
struct always_throw
{
    always_throw() { throw std::exception(); }
};

new (std::nothrow) always_throw;
```

At some point, this will allocate memory with a call to:

```
void* __memory = operator new(sizeof(always_throw), std::nothrow);
```

Since the initialization of the object throws, the compiler needs to free the allocated memory with a matching deallocation function, so it does:

```
operator delete(__memory, std::nothrow);
```

Calling the `std::nothrow_t` version.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such form of `delete`, because `delete` does not throw, since:

1. It performs no allocations.
2. It's often used in destructors which should not throw!

Items created with the `nothrow` version of new, will return NULL instead of throwing a bad_alloc exception. Using `delete` on NULL is perfectly valid, so there is no situation where it should throw.

Comment: Oh. But in complete reference c++ book, its given that it exists and i saw different different opinions in internet, hence the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean "they were not allocated from the heap"? It still allocates memory, it just won't throw if it can't.

Comment: This answer is still wrong, or at least ambiguous. There is no `delete` expression that can call `operator delete(..., std::nothrow)`, but that operator still exists.

Answer (score 2):

For most practical purposes, there's only one version of delete. The `new(nothrow)` is written as a placement new operator, but for the most part, there's no corresponding version for delete. The only exception to that is a version of delete that gets invoked when a placement new throws -- but since (in this case) you've assured that the `new` can't throw, that version of delete is of no real use/help here.